# IF condition is met, write "string" and goto next

Tags: vba, excel

I have this line:

```
If UCase(Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("G" & i).Value) Like "*TAX*" Then GoTo Skip1
```

What I need is to insert something like this:

```
IF condition is met, write "string" Then GoTo Skip1
```

The above should continue to execute the rest of the code normally, if condition is NOT met.

How should I approach the Syntax?

I tried a BUNCH of things. Else, ElseIF always populating the object as:

```
(Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("G" & i).Value) = "string"
```

and it is giving me multiple errors. 
EndIF without IF
Expected statement, object, line  etc

*********************************EDIT 1************************************

This is the whole code - modified with the suggestion:

```
Sub Categories_Update()
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim PatternFound As Boolean

    Call speedup

    lastrow = Sheets("Rules").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow2 = Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 4 To lastrow2

    ' *** This is where we can insert, a conditional that causes the row to get skipped based on
    'column G being "CYRRILIC TEXT" - aka Auto Tax - this conditional sends it to the part "Skip1" down below

        If UCase(Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("G" & i).value) Like "*TAX*" Then
            Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("M" & i).value = "Automatic Tax"
            GoTo Skip1

            PatternFound = False

            j = 1


        Do While PatternFound = False And j < lastrow
            j = j + 1
            If UCase(Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("L" & i).value) Like "*" & UCase(Sheets("Rules").Range("A" & j).value) & "*" Then
                Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("M" & i).value = Sheets("Rules").Range("C" & j).value
                PatternFound = True
            End If
        Loop

Skip1:

    Next i

Call normal

End Sub

Public Sub speedup()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
End Sub

Public Sub normal()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Unfortunately this gives me an error   -> **Compile Error:   Next Without For**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should do that:

```
If UCase(Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("G" & i).value) Like "*TAX*" Then
    Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("G" & i).value = "string"
    GoTo Skip1
End If
```

**[EDIT]**

You should make proper indentation in your code - it would be much easier for you to find such mistakes. You forgot to close `For ... Next` statement.

I found also another error in your code. You should move those two lines:

```
PatternFound = False
j = 1
```

before `GoTo Skip1` label. Otherwise they will never be executed.

Below is your code with all those errors corrected:

```
Sub Categories_Update()
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim PatternFound As Boolean

    Call speedup

    lastrow = Sheets("Rules").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow2 = Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 4 To lastrow2

        ' *** This is where we can insert, a conditional that causes the row to get skipped based on
        'column G being "CYRRILIC TEXT" - aka Auto Tax - this conditional sends it to the part "Skip1" down below

        If UCase(Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("G" & i).value) Like "*TAX*" Then
            Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("M" & i).value = "Automatic Tax"

            'NOTE: Those two lines must be before [GoTo Skip1]. Otherwise, ----------|
            'they won't be executed.                                                '|
            PatternFound = False                                                    '|
            j = 1                                                                   '|
            '------------------------------------------------------------------------|

            GoTo Skip1

        End If

        Do While PatternFound = False And j < lastrow
            j = j + 1

            If UCase(Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("L" & i).value) Like "*" & UCase(Sheets("Rules").Range("A" & j).value) & "*" Then
                Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("M" & i).value = Sheets("Rules").Range("C" & j).value
                PatternFound = True
            End If

        Loop
Skip1:

    Next i

    Call normal

End Sub

Public Sub speedup()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
End Sub

Public Sub normal()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Now I understand! Thank you. I saw where I was missing the End If statement that closes the first block (doh) 

Amazing! Thank you very much